# Entity manager for specified entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, configuration, entitymanager

I have multiple managers and configuration of one of them is like this

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    entity_managers:
      support:
        connection: support
        mappings:
          APIBundle: ~
```

But there are tens of entities in APIBundle and I need only some of them in this manager. What a correct configuration should be in such case?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything in the doctrine documentation which match with what you're asking.

But by reading [the mapping part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration), we can imagine a little trick to pass through that :

Define your entities in two distinct folders :

```
APIBundle
|
--- Em1Entity
|
--- SupportEntity
```

Then in your config, specify the `dir` configuration :

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    entity_managers:
      support:
        connection: support
        mappings:
          Support:
            mapping:              true
            type:                 ~
            dir:                  APIBundle\SupportEntity
            alias:                ~
            prefix:               ~
            is_bundle:            ~
```

It's just a guess, I didn't personnaly tested this hack.